# radio button how to pre select value with the value determined in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a method like:

```
$('.officeapprovalspan').click(function () {

        var invoicelineid = $(this).data("invoicelineid");

        var approval = $(this).data("approval");

        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="radio" name="variety" value="null" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="pleaseapprove">Please Accept</span><br >' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="variety" value="false" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="onhold">On Hold</span><br >' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="variety" value="true" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="accepted">Accepted</span>');

        $(document).on('change', '.radioapproval', radiohandler);
    });
```

So, I have the three radio buttons. What I want to achieve is based on the value of the variable approval preselect the appropriate radio button. Approval will have the value null, false or true.

Can someone please tell me how you would write this given I'm adding it with the replaceWith

Comment: what value does `approval` contain for instance ?

Comment: oh sorry, should have said, either null, false or true

Comment: what values are expected in `var approval`

Comment: @AnonyMouse: doesn't make much sense to me. I would expect that there should be some kind of "identifier" (class name for instance) as value so you know which radio to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.html()`:

```
var invoicelineid = $(this).data("invoicelineid");
var approval = $(this).data("approval");

$(this).html(
    '<input type="radio" name="variety" value="null" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="pleaseapprove">Please Accept</span><br >' +
    '<input type="radio" name="variety" value="false" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="onhold">On Hold</span><br >' +
    '<input type="radio" name="variety" value="true" class="radioapproval" data-invoicelineid=' + invoicelineid + ' /><span class="accepted">Accepted</span>'
)
.find(':radio[name="variety"][value="' + approval + '"]')
.prop('checked', true);
```

For example if the value of the `approval` variable is `true` the last radio button will be selected.